# How to extract 2.00 and 5.00 from "2.00 pm to 5.00 pm" using jquery

Tags: jquery

Any one please help me to **extract 2.00 and 5.00  from `"2.00 pm to 5.00 pm"**` using jQuery.

Comment: How robust does this need to be? Is it okay to just split by space and take the first and fourth word?

Comment: And don't you need to at least also get "am/pm" ?

Comment: i want to split “2.00 pm to 5.00 pm” into 15 minutes interval using jquery such that the result will be the following.
2.00
2.15
2.30
2.45
3.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

```js
console.log(
  "2.00 pm to 5.00 pm".match(/\d{1,2}\.\d{2}/g)
)
```

Comment: there is a comma before the answer. how to remove that comma

Comment: @JishnuRS : comma where?

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan: at begining

Comment: @JishnuRS : sorry i couldn't get you :(